# how to create a responsive footer in material?

Tags: css, angular-material, material-ui

I am trying to develop a page footer in angular 6. I am using angular material and not using bootstrap.

Can anyone help to change this code into the angular material syntax?

I want to convert this footer into the full responsive Material UI design.

If possible then can I make this footer as responsive as well?

```css
            .app-footer {
          margin-top: 2em;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align:middle;
          min-height: 100%
        }
        
        .app-footer-link { 
          line-height: 1.5em;
        }
        
        .app-footer-link p {
            margin: 0;
        }
    
        .row/*:after*/ {
      display: flex;
      /*content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;*/
    }
    
    .firstrow/*:after*/ {
      display: flex;
      /*content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;*/
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .column {
      flex: 25%;
      /*width:20%;*/
      float:left;
      font-size:12px;
    }
    .headingcolumn {
      flex: 25%;
      /*width:20%;*/
      float:left;
      font-size:18px;
      /*line-height:12px;*/
    }
    .maincolumnleft {
      flex: 50%;
      /*width: 50%;*/
      float: left;
    }
    .maincolumnright {
      /*flex: 50%;*/
      width: 50%;
      float: right;
    }
    .fullcolumn {
      width: 100%;
      /*flex:100%;*/
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .heading{
      font-size:18px;
    }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .column {
        /*flex:100%;*/
        width: 100%;
      }
      .headingcolumn {
        /*flex: 100%;*/
        width: 100%;
      }
      .maincolumnleft {
        /*flex: 100%;*/
        width: 100%;
      }
      .maincolumnright {
        /*flex: 100%;*/
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
 

     ------------footer.component.html---------------------------
        <footer class="app-footer">
      <div class="app-footer-link">
        <div class="firstrow">
          <div class="headingcolumn"></div>
          <div class="headingcolumn">B</div>
          <div class="headingcolumn">S</div>
          <div class="headingcolumn">About Us</div>
          <div class="headingcolumn">C Service</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column"></div>
          <div class="column">New Acc</div>
          <div class="column">New Acc</div>
          <div class="column">About</div>
          <div class="column">Help</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column"></div>
          <div class="column">Cat</div>
          <div class="column">St</div>
          <div class="column">Sit</div>
          <div class="column">Contact Us</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="fullcolumn">
            <span class="heading">Follow:</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="fullcolumn">
            Copyright &copy; {{getYear()}} 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </footer>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the problem you are facing?

Comment: please see above now

Comment: Did you check the `media-queries` code? Maybe there might be some kind of mistake.

Comment: Didn't understand. can you explain ?

Comment: Instead of using `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`, just use `@media  (max-width: 600px)`.

Comment: Remove `screen and` from all `media-queries` and try again.

Comment: ok i have done this but still not responsive. and can we convert it to angular material as well?

Comment: Can you share your code workspace with me, so that I can look into the code properly?

Comment: Using Atom (Teletype) or VS Code (Live Code Share)

Comment: Mittal. code is large but i think the actual code part is already mentioned above. do u want to know anything ?

Comment: I was talking about debugging, it is possible that I might find some bug. If you want you can set the restriction to codeshare as read-only.

Comment: Thank you Yashu but there is no issue or bug in at code side.  The whole thing is mentioned in above post. The actual issue is when using display:flex. If i don't use flex then it works otherwise flex doesn't grow as expected.

Comment: Try using `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated

```css
    footer{
      background: tomato;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap; /*flex items will wrap onto multiple lines, from top to bottom.*/
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .section-top{
     background: yellow;
     display: flex; 
     justify-content: center; /*items are centered along the line*/
     padding: 20px 0;
     }
    .section-bottom{
      background: blue;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 15px 0;
    }
    .col{
      margin: 0 15px;
      width: 25% /*optional*/
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 600px){ /*style if screen size is <600px*/
    .section-top{
        flex-direction: column;
    }    
    .col{
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0
    }
}
```

```html
    <footer>
    <section class="section-top">
      <div class="col">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        <div>Line 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        <div>Line 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>Line 2</div>
        <div>Line 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div>Line 2</div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section-bottom">
      <div>Follow</div>
      <div>Copy right</div>
    </section>
    </footer>
```

Comment: thank you guys, but unfortunately my major problem is still there. I again try to explain. I want to make it responsive. responsive means whenever user open it on 480 or 600 resolution then application should display all content 'll be stacked in one column . Suppose first row have 3 columns, now it 'll be 3 rows and column will be one.

Comment: it can easily be done by `@media all and (min-width: 600px)` and  `@media all and (min-width: 480px)` to set your styles at different screensize, then you can stack the divs on top of each other if it's less than 480px screen size or whatever you want to do with it. i'll add an example to the code